# Time based restriction on react native

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-native

I am kind of new in react native. looking for advise on how to approach.

So I am trying to make few buttons with a feature that will only allow users on specific time slots. such as there is a button **Morning slot** with these feature

1. only allows from 9am to 10 am
2. if not during the time, toast that come back at 9 am

This is really unusual feature, but I really need to implement this.
Any suggestion how to approach limiting the onPress functionality based on time?

Answer (score 1):

If it is the button that has the time slot, you can use Date function to get the current Hour and have a check to disable the button when it is outside of your time slot.

```
var hours = new Date().getHours(); //To get the Current Hours
```

If it is the User that has the time slot, you'll need to store the user in a database and on the user object save the time. The app will then check the user's stored timeslot to disable the button.

Disable the button like so:

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={checkTimeSlot()}>
  <Text>I'm disabled</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Then have a helper function `checkTimeSlot()` which has the logic of checking the time/User

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too difficult to implement, you just have to put the time logic in the press handler. on every press you get a new date (new Date()) from which you extract the current hour (new Date().getHours()) and then with a switch case in the handler you execute what you wish. Here is a snack that shows this working :). https://snack.expo.io/@bitxhgunner/time-based-logic . Be advised that the time shown in the alert boxes may vary because the server is in a different timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
export default function App() {

  const handlePress = () => {
    const current = new Date();
    const currentHour = current.getHours();
    if( currentHour == 9 || currentHour == 10 ){
      alert("Time is correct");
    } else {
      alert("Come back at 9am");
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
        <Text>Morning slot</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```